# Numba: Accessing Class attributes in a jitted function

Tags: python, numba

I have the following simple problem.

```
import numba
import numpy as np

class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.Value=0.0
       self.Array=np.array([],dtype=np.float64)

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def Fun(ClassInstance):
    print ClassInstance.Array*1.0
```

When I execute these simple lines

```
A=MyClass()
Fun(A)
```

I get the following error:

```
numba/dataflow.py:346: RuntimeWarning: Python2 style print partially supported.  Please use Python3 style print.
  "Python3 style print.", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "numba/dispatcher.py", line 310, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
numba.errors.UntypedAttributeError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba/compiler.py", line 230, in run
    stage()
  File "numba/compiler.py", line 444, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "numba/compiler.py", line 800, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "numba/typeinfer.py", line 767, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
UntypedAttributeError: Unknown attribute 'Array' of type pyobject
File "bumba.py", line 11
[1] During: typing of get attribute at bumba.py (11)

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'Array' of type pyobject
File "bumba.py", line 11
[1] During: typing of get attribute at bumba.py (11)

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

It escapes me why numba doesn't recognize the array. Since it's such a basic functionality, I must assume that I'm missing something crucial, but I have so far not found any solutions.

Comment: You forbade it from accessing any Python APIs with `nopython=True` and then told it to access a Python API with `ClassInstance.Array`.

Comment: If you want to access arbitrary Python object attributes, you need to turn off nopython.

Comment: So help me find the error in my thinking, please. According to Numba's description 'nopython' merely prohibits Python's C API. I was unaware that accessing an attribute constitutes accessing the C API.

Comment: The only way to make Numba recognize an arbitrary class instance in `nopython` mode is if that class instance is of a `jitclass`: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html The numba documentation keeps an up-to-date list of all of the builtin python functionality it supports in `nopython` mode: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html

Comment: For types Numba doesn't recognize, attribute access is PyObject_GetAttr, and it can invoke arbitrary code. Don't think of the C API as a special thing you'd have to go out of your way to invoke; *any* Python API will have to be accessed through the C API unless Numba has special handling for it.

Comment: @user2357112, I for one would have appreciated that clarification in the documentation of 'nopython'.

Comment: @JoshAdel, I had read those links, but they failed to clarify my above problem. For instance, using attributes from classes is not explicitly listed as a missing functionality, maybe the lack of support for class definitions implies it, but that is not clear to me. jitclass doesn't help either in this case.

Comment: @Deathbreath the documentation is a list of supported features. Anything not listed should be assumed to not be supported. My advice would be, if feasible, to pass the attributes into the function explicitly rather than passing the object. As along as the attributes are numpy arrays or scalars, then you should be able to use them in `nopython` mode. Some python objects like namedtuples and basic builtin datastructures are also ok.

Comment: @JoshAdel, despite the documentation's claims that is factually incorrect. The very first entry on constructs is a mixture of white- and blacklisting. Similarly for generators.

Answer (score 1):

As @user2537112 indicates in the comments, Numba's `nopython` option to `jit` leads to an invocation of the Python C API via PyObject_GetAttr, because Numba does not currently support attribute access. Workarounds include passing the object attributes directly to the function instead of through the object instance.